# Spark streaming mapWithState mem increasing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

So I have this code

```
KafkaUtils.
      createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, fromOffsets)
      map(event => (event.requestId, event.toString)).
      mapWithState(StateSpec.function(StateFunc.func _).numPartitions(200).timeout(Minutes(5))).
      foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[String]) => {
        process(rdd.filter(_ != null), sparkSession, topic, partitionsNum)
      })
```

All that the `StateFunc.func` is doing, is to update the state like so:

```
def func(batchTime: Time, key: String, event: Option[String], state: State[String]): Option[String] = {
    if (state.exists) {
      if (!state.isTimingOut()) {
        state.update(event)
      }
    } else {
      state.update(event)
    }
    event
}
```

**Edit:** all that is been done in the state function is update the sate.
But It should stopped be updated after about 2-3 times (no more events with the same key will arrive). so eventually they should be timed out and deleted by spark

All that the `process` function is doing is to write to S3 the RDDs as `json` files

After 3 batches with 3600000 records (from the spark stream UI) the output size was about ~2GB 
but the `mapWithState` was ~30GB (should be as the output size) and my cluster is only 40GB
those, after some time, the spark fails and starts over again.

Can someone help with explanation why the mapWithState size is 30+GB?
and Why the cluster sometimes fails of OutOfMemory?

**Properties:**
streamInterval is `50 sec`
maxRatePerPartition is `3000 records`
kafka partitions is `8`
backPressure is `true`
each record is about `1500 bytes`

**Update:**
So I tried running it again with small batch of ~170000 records (each record is a string with length of 264 byes) so total should be 45MB
as shown in the picture. the mapWithstate is ~350MB all the 199 stored rdds are 2.5KB and just 1 rdd is 350 MB. **what the hell?!**
[info mapWithState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IZy7.jpg)

Comment: This is usual case when spark is not able to process the record within the batch interval and after few minute this happens . Can you please check UI what the processing time when this happens .

Comment: I'll check, but with `backPressure.enable = true` this should not happen no?
spark should control the input rate if its not able to handle the batch within the window interval

Comment: @dimagol1989 can you provide more details about state function ???

Comment: Please show your `State` code, what `state.update(event)` actually does?